# kusto query - i want exclude 2nd and 4th Saturday along with Sunday on chart

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

i want exclude 2nd and 4th Saturday along with Sunday on chart.

i am trying this code but its not working it gives an error -

> Relop semantic error: SEM0025: One of the values provided to the 'in'
> operator does not match the left side expression type 'timespan',
> consider using explicit cast

```
| extend Eventdate = strcat(datetime_part("day",timestamp))
| extend day = dayofweek(timestamp)
| extend day_strg = tostring(Eventdate)
| extend Week_Num = case(
   day_strg in (range(1, 7, 1)), "1",
   day_strg in (range(8, 14, 1)), "2",
   day_strg in (range(15, 21, 1)), "3",
   day_strg in (range(22, 31, 1)), "4",
   "0")
| extend weekend = case(Week_Num in (2, 4) and day in (5, 6), "weekend","working day") 
| project Eventdate, timestamp, day, day_strg, Week_Num, weekend
```

Comment: Please add a data sample

Comment: `dayofweek` returns timespan and not an integer. Divide it by `1d` in order to get an integer: `| extend day = dayofweek(timestamp) / 1d`. That solves the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what it seems that you are asking for:

```
range timestamp from datetime(2022-02-01 08:06:45.7316316) to datetime(2022-03-01 08:06:45.7316316) step 1d
| extend DayOfMonth = dayofmonth(timestamp)
| extend Day = startofday(timestamp)
| extend Week_Num = case(
   DayOfMonth <=7, 1,
   DayOfMonth <=14, 2,
   DayOfMonth <=21, 3,
   DayOfMonth <=28, 4,
   5)
| extend weekend = iif((Week_Num in (2, 4) and (dayofweek(timestamp)/1d) == 6) or dayofweek(timestamp)/1d == 0, "weekend","working day") 
| project timestamp, Day, Week_Num, weekend
```

| timestamp | Day | Week_Num | weekend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | working day |
| 2022-02-02 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | working day |
| 2022-02-03 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | working day |
| 2022-02-04 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | working day |
| 2022-02-05 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | working day |
| 2022-02-06 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-06 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | weekend |
| 2022-02-07 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-07 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | working day |
| 2022-02-08 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-08 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | working day |
| 2022-02-09 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-09 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | working day |
| 2022-02-10 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-10 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | working day |
| 2022-02-11 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-11 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | working day |
| 2022-02-12 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-12 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | weekend |
| 2022-02-13 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-13 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | weekend |
| 2022-02-14 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-14 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | working day |
| 2022-02-15 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-15 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | working day |
| 2022-02-16 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-16 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | working day |
| 2022-02-17 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-17 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | working day |
| 2022-02-18 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-18 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | working day |
| 2022-02-19 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-19 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | working day |
| 2022-02-20 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | weekend |
| 2022-02-21 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-21 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | working day |
| 2022-02-22 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | working day |
| 2022-02-23 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-23 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | working day |
| 2022-02-24 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-24 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | working day |
| 2022-02-25 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-25 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | working day |
| 2022-02-26 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-26 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | weekend |
| 2022-02-27 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-27 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | weekend |
| 2022-02-28 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.0000000 | 4 | working day |
| 2022-03-01 08:06:45.7316316 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | working day |

Comment: the data is showing working day on 6th feb though we need to mark all sunday as weekend and 2nd and 4th saturday as weekend as well. please help.

Comment: i have added this code, would it be working...i dont have data right now for weekends. | extend weekend = iff(Week_Num in (2,4) and day_num in (0,6) and day_num == "0", "weekend", "working day")

Comment: I updated the answer above with the new specification, please check it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: you are champion sir...thank you so much.